# Error - Insert data into Access database in c#

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

Pls, am having an error code when inserting data into Access database. It keeps saying there's sytanx error in my INSERT INTO statement. Can any one help me to solve this.
Here is the code

```
try {  
            OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = C:\Users\DELL\Documents\EmployeesData.accdb;  
            Persist Security Info = false;");  
            connection.Open();  
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("insert into EmployeeInfo (UserName, Password) values('" + UserText.Text + "', '" + PassText.Text + "')", connection);  
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  
            MessageBox.Show("Inserted");  
        }  
        catch (Exception ex)  
        {  
            MessageBox.Show("Failed" + ex.ToString());  
        }
```

Comment: You could do worse than asking Little Bobby Tables for some advice...

Answer (score 3):

Password is a keyword in MSACCESS so u need to enclosed in [] bracket

```
 OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("insert into EmployeeInfo ([UserName], [Password])
 values('" + UserText.Text + "', '" + PassText.Text + "')", connection);
```

Note: always use parameterized queries to avoid SQL Injection

Comment: Not working the error code says "Index or primary key cannot contain a Null value"

Comment: @OyetokeTobiEmmanuel in your table there is a primary key and you are not passing value for it.. thats why its giving this erro